# How to know I have to blacklist acer_wmi?

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I recently bought a Xiaomi Notebook Air 13'.

As a lot of people, I met some issues with the WiFi on Ubuntu (16.04). Basically, the WiFi just did not work.

As answered on *ask ubuntu*, a simple way to fix this issue is to add **blacklist acer_wmi** in the file **blacklist.conf**.

So, my question is **not** *"How to fix this issue?"*, but my question is *"How could I know by myself ( ie. just by looking in command output like* **lsmod** *or* **lspci** *) how to fix this issue?*

For example, an extract of the output of **lspci -vv** is the following:

```
$ lspci -vv
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MenWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66Mhz UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ283
Region 0: Memory at a4100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Here, we see that **iwlwifi** is the module which drives the Wifi controller.

But I cannot find any link (when I use for example **lspci** or **lsmod**) between **iwlwifi** and **acer_wmi**.

But if I blacklist **acer_wmi**, the WiFi works fine! Why ?

For information:

```
$ lsmod | grep acer_wmi
acer_wmi       20480 0
sparse_keymap  16384 2 acer_wmi,dell_wmi_aio
wmi            16384 4 acer_wmi,mxm_wmi,dell_wmi_aio,nouveau
video          40930 3 acer_wmi,nouveau,i915
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module *iwlwifi* is the driver for your wireless device. The module *acer_wmi* is a helper module that translates key presses, Fn+F8 for example, into action, in your case, 'turn on the wireless radio, please.'

You can gain some clues from the terminal command:

```
rfkill list all
```

You may see something like this:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

As well, you may notice that any presses of the wireless or airplane mode key doesn't enable wireless. In your case, we also see:

```
$ lsmod | grep acer_wmi
acer_wmi       20480 0
sparse_keymap  16384 2 acer_wmi,dell_wmi_aio
wmi            16384 4 acer_wmi,mxm_wmi,dell_wmi_aio,nouveau
video          40930 3 acer_wmi,nouveau,i915
```

The original manufacturer of your Xiaomi is probably *not* both Acer and Dell.

As an experiment, you blacklisted *acer_wmi* and the wireless works correctly. I believe you found the correct solution!

Comment: When I blacklist **acer_wmi**, then **rfkill list all** shows that **acer-wireless** is not *soft blocked* anymore.


So, if I understand well, the WiFi did not work before just because **acer_wmi** prevented it to work, and because my Xiaomi keyboard layout (with the *airplaine mode*) does not correspond to the acer one and so is not correctly mapped with the wifi activation function of **acer_wmi** ?

Comment: Correct! May I assume that after *acer_wmi* is blacklisted and you reboot that *acer-wireless* is not shown at all in *rfkill*?

Comment: You'r assumption is alright!